# Android: Write byteArray to a file

Tags: java, android, file

I have byte[] and I want to save this byteArray to a file for that I have written this code:

```
File root = new File(App.getAppCacheDir(baseActivity) + "/user/");
if (!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();
File file = new File(root, "user.jpg");
writeBytesToFile(userImage,file);
```

at first I create patha and then I have set a name for my file and finally I have pass away path and my byteArray to my method.

this is my method:

```
    private void writeBytesToFile(byte[] bFile, File fileDest) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileDest);
        fOut.write(bFile);
        fOut.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but no file is created to my address?where is my mistake?

Comment: an IOException is probably thrown, try to use some debugger

Comment: have you debugged your code ? what error you got if you really get the file path ? I think if you are getting the path then you will be facing some exception.

Comment: there is no exception  https://ibb.co/fW9R3G

Comment: `but no file is created to my address?`. How do you know? Where did you look? Which tool did you use for that? Tell the exact full path of the file please.

Comment: @greenapps this file created but I can not open emulator.I am using and work without any problem. my address is: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.safa.notify/cache/user`

Comment: `this file created`. ?? Is it now created? But you said it was not created!? `but I can not open emulator`. What do you mean? I cannot follow you. And you did not tell which tool you use to look in that directory. Is the directory created?

Comment: `I am using and work without any problem.`  ?????

Comment: yes. I am using. mean this file was created and I just can not navigate to emulator folder from `android device monitor`. seems it is new policy from google.

Comment: You should use a file explorer app on your emulator if you want to check files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
File root = new File(App.getAppCacheDir(baseActivity) + "/user/");
if (!root.exists()) root.mkdirs();
File file = new File(root, "user.jpg");
if (!file.exists()) file.createNewFile();
writeBytesToFile(userImage,file);
```

Comment: Nothing is change.I think this is a bug for emulator:https://ibb.co/j4Xkxb

Comment: I think this is a bug for emulator: https://ibb.co/j4Xkxb.I am using API 25 android 7.1.1.(Google APIs)

Comment: If you are in Activity replace new File(App.getAppCacheDir(baseActivity) + "/user/") by getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("user")

Comment: no I am not into an activity.I am into `public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {`

Comment: So is baseActivity.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("user") if is an Activity (baseActivity)

Comment: I do you suggestion but nothing exist at `storage/emulated folder`

Comment: I trie in my phone and it work but i think you are reason is a bug emulator or restrict access to folder

Comment: I think there is a bug. now i am trying to use this file, if I do not get error.

Comment: I trie with Android Device Monitor and he don't let me in my emulated folder so i think is a restriction for acces folder

Comment: It was interesting ,then this is new policy from google and this is not a bug!!

Answer (score 1):

```
     String s = "Java Code Geeks - Java Examples";
    File file = new File("outputfile.txt"); 
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        // Writes bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream

        fos.write(s.getBytes());
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception while writing file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the streams using close method
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }
```